# split a string to array containing pairs of two

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this: `56f7gg5cx887r7gt8r6t7`.

Besides splitting it into an array of one and then looping by two `i+2` and creating another array with entries containing two by two.

Is there a simpler way?

The result should be like this: `['56','f7','gg','5c','x8','87','r7','gt','8r','6t','7']`.

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259515/javascript-elegant-way-to-split-string-into-segments-n-characters-long

Comment: Because it sounds like a case of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Why I need this is irrelevant, besides it would take a sizable long explication to do so, and it is not needed for an answer. I got my answer. Thank you.

Comment: My use case is that I have a date string of the form `'YYYYMMDDhhmmss'`.  Splitting that into pairs will make for much easier processing than 6 different substrings.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
'56f7gg5cx887r7gt8r6t7'.match(/(..?)/g)
```