# A operation to split a string to several part

Tags: javascript

I want to show the type is 123 456 789 after I get the string 123456789. I used the method like following, but I do not think it is a great way, so does anyone has a better way ?

```
let num = '123456789'
let result = num.slice(0,3)+ ' '+num.slice(3,6)+ ' '+num.slice(6,9) // result = '123 456 789'
```

Comment: Clear duplicate of [Javascript elegant way to split string into segments n characters long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259515/javascript-elegant-way-to-split-string-into-segments-n-characters-long)

Answer (score 6):

You can use a global regular expression and `match` 3 digits, then join by spaces:

```js
let num = '123456789';
const result = num
  .match(/\d{3}/g)
  .join(' ');
console.log(result);
```

Or, with `.replace` and lookahead for another digit:

```js
let num = '123456789';
const result = num.replace(/\d{3}(?=\d)/g, '$& ');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do that using while loop and `slice()`

```js
let str = '123456789';
function splitBy(str,num){
  let result = '';
  while(str.length > num){
    result += str.slice(0,3) + ' ';
    str = str.slice(3);
  }
  return result + str;
}
console.log(splitBy(str,3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)** to return an array of chunks based on the split-length provided. Then use [**`join()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to concatenate them

```js
let num = '123456789'

function getChunks(string, n) {
  const length = Math.ceil(string.length / n);
  return Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => string.slice(i * n, (i + 1) * n))
}

console.log(getChunks(num, 3).join(' '))
console.log(getChunks(num, 4).join(' '))
```