# Javascript detecting 2 digit numbers in a string

Tags: javascript, numbers

Let's say the user gives us a string "12345678" it is easy to separate each digit. If user inputs "899091929394" (2 digit number series) I can't understand how to separate the long string into 2 digit numbers. Further on what if a user inputs 3 digit number series.

My question is: How to detect and separate multi-digit numbers from a long string?

Result should look like Array = [89,90,91,92,93,94]

Comment: please add the result.

Comment: Please stop putting minuses and just give advice on what to improve in the question, the person is new here.

Comment: First you need a separator between all the numbers otherwise you will not be able to find that when one number is completing and other is starting.

Comment: Maybe this answer helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259515/javascript-elegant-way-to-split-string-into-segments-n-characters-long

Comment: May be this will help : "899091929394".match(/(\d{2})/g)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to separate until you got every item in a series.

```js
function separate(s) {
    var i = 1,
        temp;
    
    while (i < s.length) {
        temp = s.match(new RegExp(`.{${i}}`, 'g')).map(Number);
        if (temp.every((v, i, a) => !i || a[i - 1] + 1 === v || a[i - 1] + 2 === v)) {
            return temp;
        }
        i++;
    }
}


var strings = ["12345678", "8788909192", "899091929394", "234235236237238239"],
    result = strings.map(separate);

result.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

Comment: Can you explain what this part of code (v, i, a) => !i || a[i - 1] + 1 === v) is as this function works perfectly but does not complete my assignment as in I need to modify this part.

Comment: `v` is the value, `i` the index and `a` the array. because you need to chekc two elements, the first element has no predecessor, so `!i` returns `true` for index zero and for all other indices, the second part is evaluated by taking the last element, add one and compare with the actual value.

Comment: So if let's say I have to make this work even if numbers are missing in series eg "8788909192" I can just switch .every with .some?

Comment: no, you need still `every`, but if you have holes of one, then add another check, like `!i || a[i - 1] + 1 === v || a[i - 1] + 2 === v`

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want:

```js
const string = "899091929394";

const splittedString = string.match(/.{1,2}/g);

console.log(splittedString);
```

OUTPUT:

```
[ '89', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94' ]
```

If you want to change the "group by" number, edit the regex `/.{1,2}/g`.

Comment: Add the code in snippet that will make answer more interactive and easy to see output. +1

Comment: it is not really dynamic.

Comment: @NinaScholz what do you mean with dynamic?

Comment: the question: "*How to detect and separate multi-digit numbers from a long string?*"

Comment: @NinaScholz how to descriminate between multi-digit numbers? How do we know if it is 2 digit serie or more?

Comment: right, that is the question. i [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55001722/1447675) to spearate the string beginning with a length of one character, check if any predecessor plus one is equal to the actual item. if so, return this array, otherwise increment the part string length.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function seperateNDigitsFromNumber(numberInput, digitsCount) {
        const regexString = new RegExp("\\d{1,"+digitsCount+"}", "g");
        return numberInput
        .match(regexString)
        .map(stringNum => parseInt(stringNum, 10));
}

seperateNDigitsFromNumber("899091929394",2);
```

**Example :**
**seperateNDigitsFromNumber("899091929394",2) => [89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94]**