# Javascript how to split or break 6 digit number

Tags: javascript, typescript

Im generating a simple random number which is generating 6 digit number. i want to break it in two parts 3 by 3. Example if number is 456123 it will break line number1=456 and number2=123

Im generating number like this

```
Number = Math.random().toString().substr(-6);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript elegant way to split string into segments n characters long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259515/javascript-elegant-way-to-split-string-into-segments-n-characters-long)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Regex `match()` like this

```
Math.random().toString().substr(-6).match(/.{1,3}/g)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this numerically rather than converting to a string, you can do the math to get both parts using mod 1000 for the right part and then subtract and divide the left:

```js
let n = 456123

let r = n % 1000
let l = (n - r) / 1000

console.log(l, r)
```

This assumes you want `0` if the right part is `0` rather than the string `000` (which you can get by padding it if you need that).

Comment: This is _probably_ the fastest but definitely the sanest.

Comment: Yeah, @Evert, it seems much faster to stick with numbers -- thought both are probably fast enough and the string might be more convenient depending on the use: https://jsperf.com/to-string-v-mod/1