# How to split a richembed description into two messages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I’m trying to work out how to split a RichEmbed into two separate messages if the description is larger than 2048 characters.

```js
let embed = new RichEmbed()
                .setColor(cyan)
                .setAuthor(`Urban Dictionary | ${word}`, image)
                .setThumbnail(image)
                .setDescription(stripIndents`**Definition:** 
                ${definition || "No definition"}
                **Example:** 
                ${example || "No example"}
                **Upvotes:** ${thumbs_up || 0}
                **Downvotes:** ${thumbs_down || 0}
                **Link:** [Link to ${word}](${permalink || "https://www.urbandictionary.com/"})`)
                .setFooter(`Requested by: ${message.author.tag} || Author: ${author || "Unknown"}`, message.author.avatarURL)
                .setTimestamp()

                message.channel.send(embed)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by setting your description as a variable. Then, you can use the regex from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6259543) to split the description up into segments 2,048 characters long. Finally, iterate through the resulting array and send an embed with each segment of the original string.

Example code:

```js
const description = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.';
const split = description.match(/[\s\S]{1,2048}/g);

for (let i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
  let embed = new RichEmbed()
    .setDescription(split[i]);

  await message.channel.send(embed) // Async context needed to use 'await.'
    .catch(console.error);  
}
```