# Can be a type in Typescript defined to have a combination of characters?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, string-literals

Let me explain by example.

In a Field called `Component` you should be able to have these values> "M", "B", "A.

So you go ahead an define:
`type Component = "M" | "B" | "A";`

So far so good. But it should be possible to also have a combination of these to assign like this:
`const MyComponent : Component = "MB";`
or
`const MyComponent : Component = "BA";`

How to define that?

Comment: hmm maybe this could a solution some time in the future https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simply find an interface for your data** - it looks like you have a simple small set of values as a domain data for `Component` property. So maybe you should just extend your type (union):

```
type Component = "M" | "B" | "A" | "MA"
```

What do you think about introducing enum (string)?

```
enum Direction {
    A: "A",
    B: "B",
    M: "M",
    AB: "AB",
    // more values
}
```

At the end - don't think about data type as validator. So maybe in your case you should just use simple type "string" and validate it on demand or at initialization time.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with TypeScript 4.1 this is possible with [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types).
E.g.:

```
type Component = "M" | "B" | "A";
type ComponentCombination = `${Component}${Component}`;

const comb: ComponentCombination = "MB";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible using TypeScript, but you can validate such a string using RegEx, the following thread gives an example of how to do that:
[How can I split a string into segments of n characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259515/how-can-i-split-a-string-into-segments-of-n-characters)

You can also use this regex:

```
let value = 'MBA';

// string length 1-3 and contains M,B,A combinations
let validatorRegEx = /^([M|B|A]{1,3}$)/i; 
if(validatorRegEx.test(value)) {
    // code ...
}
```