# VueJS: Computed Calculation Assistance

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to be able to convert a string (IP address) such as this `10.120.0.1` to a string (ISIS Network ID) such as this `49.0001.0101.2000.0001.00`. The middle section `010 1.20 00.0 001` corresponds to the first string (I've spaced them out to show the IP address is inside it). You can see that there are 4 digits in each ISIS Network ID hextet that need to correspond to 3 digits in the IP Address octet. A number of `53` for example would have a leading `0` to make 3 digits.

All the IP addresses start with `10.120.` so I just need to inject the last 2 octets from the IP Address into the ISIS Network ID.

I need this to be dynamic so when someone types in another ip address into a `loopbackIP` input, it automatically updates the `isisNetworkID` field.

I have this:

`49.0001.0101.{{ isisNetworkID }}.00`

This needs to take the value from an input `v-model="loopbackIP"` that I have and translate the remaining values to sit in the middle of that `isisNetworkID` following this format - `xxxx.xxxx`.

I've got this computed calculation but I'm not sure how to make 4 digits equal 3...

```
const loopbackIP = '10.120.0.1';

const isisNetworkID = computed(() => {
    let idaho = '10.120.';

    if (loopbackIP.indexOf(idaho)) {
        return loopbackIP.slice(7);
    } else {
        console.log('Nothing is happening');
    }
});
```

I hope this makes sense...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to achieve. Let's break it down into digestible parts. You have an IP address of:

```
10.120.0.1
```

And you want to transform it such that each part is padded to 3 digits:

```
['010', '120', '000', '001']
```

This can be done by splitting the string by the `.` character, and the using [`String.prototype.padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart). We then join the array back into a string:

```
'010120000001'
 ||||
 ^^^^ -> to be deleted
```

We know that the first 4 digits is not needed, since it's already part of your template, so we can remove them using [`String.prototype.substring(4)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring). That leaves us with:

```
'20000001'
```

Now it is just the matter of [splitting it into 4 characters per item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259515/how-can-i-split-a-string-into-segments-of-n-characters):

```
['2000', '0001']
```

...and rejoining it with `.` character:

```
'2000.0001'
```

...and interpolating it back into the string. I have a proof-of-concept example below, which should output the desired string:

```js
const loopbackIP = '10.120.0.1';
const parts = loopbackIP.split('.').map(x => x.padStart(3, '0'));

// Remove the first 4 characters
let isisNetworkId = parts.join('');
isisNetworkId = isisNetworkId.substring(4);

const output = `49.0001.0101.${isisNetworkId.match(/.{4}/g).join('.')}.00`;
console.log(output);
```

So if you want to translate it to your VueJS code, it should look no different that this:

```
const loopbackIP = '10.120.0.1';

const isisNetworkID = computed(() => {
    const loopbackIP = '10.120.0.1';
    const parts = loopbackIP.split('.').map(x => x.padStart(3, '0'));

    let isisNetworkId = parts.join('');
    isisNetworkId = isisNetworkId.substring(4);

    // Rejoin, split into items of 4-character long, rejoin by period
    return isisNetworkId.match(/.{4}/g).join('.');
});
```

Comment: You sir, are a life saver. Thank you!