# Split Strings into pairs of characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have this problem to solve:

> split the input string into pairs of characters. If the input string has a length that is odd, then it should replace the missing second character of the final pair with an underscore `'_'`.

I solved it with this solution, and it works fine with odd string, but with even string, it gives me  `undefined`
which is not correct. because it has to just split the characters into pairs.

The input is a string and the output should be an array
for example
`splitPairs('abc');//--> [ 'ab', 'c_' ]`

This is my code:

```js
const splitPairs = (input) => {
  if(!input) return [];
  input = input.split(' ');
  let pairs = [];
  if(input.length % 2 !== 0) {input += '_'}
  for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i+= 2) {
    pairs.push(`${input[i] + input[i+1]}`)
  }
  return pairs;
}

let result1 = splitPairs('abc');//--> [ 'ab', 'c_' ]
console.log(result1);

let result2 = splitPairs('abcdef');//--> [ 'ab', 'cd', 'ef' ]
console.log(result2);

let result3 = splitPairs('retrograde');//--> [ 're', 'tr', 'og', 'ra', 'de' ]
console.log(result3);

let result4 = splitPairs('endurance');//--> [ 'en', 'du', 'ra', 'nc', 'e_' ]
console.log(result4);

let result5 = splitPairs('');//--> []
console.log(result5);
```

Comment: Why are you splitting on space? Also, when you get to `input += '_'`, `input` is an array, not a string. I'd advise against overwriting your function parameters

Comment: `+=` when the left hand side is an array converts to string. You probably didn't mean to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I split a string into segments of n characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259515/how-can-i-split-a-string-into-segments-of-n-characters)

Comment: (If this is a job interview question or a school exercise, though, stick to tweaking your original code instead.)

Comment: @Phil the output should be an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating an array, you can directly access characters of the string with bracket notation.

```js
const splitPairs = (input) => {
  if(!input) return [];
  let pairs = [];
  if(input.length % 2 !== 0) {input += '_'}
  for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i+= 2) {
    pairs.push(`${input[i] + input[i+1]}`)
  }
  return pairs;
}

let result1 = splitPairs('abc');//--> [ 'ab', 'c_' ]
console.log(result1);

let result2 = splitPairs('abcdef');//--> [ 'ab', 'cd', 'ef' ]
console.log(result2);

let result3 = splitPairs('retrograde');//--> [ 're', 'tr', 'og', 'ra', 'de' ]
console.log(result3);

let result4 = splitPairs('endurance');//--> [ 'en', 'du', 'ra', 'nc', 'e_' ]
console.log(result4);

let result5 = splitPairs('');//--> []
console.log(result5);
```