# In Javascript, split a string of words into an array of strings of grouped words, grouping for every N characters

Tags: javascript, string

[How can I split a string into segments of n characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259515/how-can-i-split-a-string-into-segments-of-n-characters) is similar but not exactly what we are trying to achieve:

```
// let splitSentence = (sentence, nChar) => {} // creating this function
let sentence = 'the quick cucumber fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
splitSentence(sentence, 15)

// output we are trying to get
// ['the quick cucumber', 'fox jumps over', 'the lazy dog.']
```

We cannot string split only on spaces, since multiple words are needed in each array element, not just a single word. The process, for `nChar == 15`, 15 letters are counted into the string, which gets to `the quick cucum`. The function should finish the word and add `the quick cucumber` into the output array as first element, then continue counting from the remainder of the sentence, starting at the next word `fox`, and repeat this process. Not sure if `.match()` with start and end indexes works for our problem like it does for the SO post linked above.

Putting this logic into splitSentence(). So far we have:

```
let splitSentence = (sentence, nChar) => {
    let output = [];
    let i = 0;
    while (i < sentence.length) {
        let partOfSentence = sentence.slice(i, i + 15);
        output.push(partOfSentence)
        i = i + 15
    }
    return output;
}
```

However, getting `['the quick cucum', 'ber fox jumps o', 'ver the lazy do', 'g.']`, which is not what is needed. Not sure how to keep the entire word together in the slice when we loop over the string.

Comment: When you are slicing, check the last character or next character; if it's a space, you're good, but if it's not, increase your slice size until you hit a space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach:

- Split the sentence into single characters
- Loop over the characters: for every character decide:

  - Is it still part of the current character group?
    This is the case if we have less then the maximum amount of `nChar` character is the group until now or if we have already overstepped that limit but are still not at the end of the word (= the character we're processing is not a word separator like in your example `space`)
  - If it is not the part of the current character group we need to create a new group, increase the group count and reset the character count.

As a result of the above process we will get an array of character arrays (`string[][]`), so we now need to loop over all our groups and join the individual characters of a character group back together using [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```js
/**
 * 
 * @param {string} sentence 
 * @param {number} nChar 
 * @returns 
 */
const splitSentence = (sentence, nChar) => {
  const chars = sentence.split("");
  let charCount = 0;
  let groupCount = 0;
  const characterGroups = chars.reduce((groups, char) => {
    // if we don't have enough characters or we still have a word to process add the character to the group
    if(charCount < nChar || char != " ") groups[groupCount].push(char)
    else {
      // we have reached the max. number of character and we also are at the end of word
      // => we need to create a new group
      groups.push([])
      // increase group count so we now add characters to a new group
      groupCount++;
      // reset character count
      charCount = 0;
    }
    charCount++;
    return groups;
  }, [[]]);
  return characterGroups.map(group => group.join(""));
} 

const sentence = 'the quick cucumber fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
console.log(splitSentence(sentence, 15));
```

```css
/* StackOverflow snippet: console should overlap rendered HTML area */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### Addition

If you want to include the spaces in your output you will only need to change one line:

```js
// instead of
groups.push([])
// use
groups.push([char])
```

Here the same code with the change so you can see how it affects the result:

```js
/**
 * 
 * @param {string} sentence 
 * @param {number} nChar 
 * @returns 
 */
const splitSentence = (sentence, nChar) => {
  const chars = sentence.split("");
  let charCount = 0;
  let groupCount = 0;
  const characterGroups = chars.reduce((groups, char) => {
    // if we don't have enough characters or we still have a word to process add the character to the group
    if(charCount < nChar || char != " ") groups[groupCount].push(char)
    else {
      // we have reached the max. number of character and we also are at the end of word
      // => we need to create a new group
      groups.push([char])
      // increase group count so we now add characters to a new group
      groupCount++;
      // reset character count
      charCount = 0;
    }
    charCount++;
    return groups;
  }, [[]]);
  return characterGroups.map(group => group.join(""));
} 

const sentence = 'the quick cucumber fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
console.log(splitSentence(sentence, 15));
```

```css
/* StackOverflow snippet: console should overlap rendered HTML area */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents here.

```
let sentence = 'the quick cucumber fox jumps over the lazy dog.';
let output = [];
const limit = 15;

const check = (sentence, nchar) => {
  let tempSentence = sentence;
  if (sentence[nchar] != ' ') {
  nchar = nchar + 1;
  check(sentence, nchar);
} else {
  output.push(sentence.substring(0, nchar).trim());
  tempSentence = sentence.substring(nchar, sentence.length);

  nchar = limit;
  if (tempSentence.length < nchar) {
    output.push(tempSentence.trim());
    return;
  }
  check(tempSentence, limit);
}

check(sentence, limit);
```