# How do I split long message, and send them in sequence?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, split, telegram-bot, message

Disclaimer I am a newbie at programing and also not really good at english, so please pardon my bad explanation.

My bot had to send a message containing data retrieved from a spreadsheet, but found that the data was so many that it exceeded the character limit of the telegram message (4096 characters).

So I assume that I have to split the message, then send them  in sequence. Please help...

here's my code :

```
function SearchbyProjectName(Prjct){
  var projectNON = GetAllProjectNON(); 
  var project = GetAllProject();
  var num = 1;
  const allLocation = [];

  var header = 
  'xxxheaderxxx';

  var footer =
  'xxxfooterxxx'

  for (var row=0; row<projectNON.length; row++) {
    if(projectNON[row][3]==Prjct){ 
      var resiNON = num++ + '. ) ' + '/d_' + projectNON[row][6] + '\n\n';
      allLocation.push(resiNON);
    }
  }
  for (var row=0; row<project.length; row++) {
    if(project[row][3]==Prjct){ 
      var resi = num++ + '. ) ' + '/d_' + project[row][6] + '\n\n';
      allLocation.push(resi);
    }
  }

  var stringg = allLocation.toString();
  var clearComma = stringg.replaceAll(",", "")
  var newData = header + clearComma + footer;
    
  return newData ;
}
```

here's the message :

ALL LOCATION
Project: PTT2
 : Tuesday, 24 Jan 2023 15:10:34

1. ) /d_XXXXXXXXXXX
2. ) /d_XXXXXXXXXXXXX
3. ) /d_XXXX
4. ) /d_DDDDDD
5. ) /d_JJJJJJJJJJJJJ
6. ) /d_XXXXXXX

...

155. ) /d_BBBBBBBBBBBBB

I wish I could split the message at number 100.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I split a string into segments of n characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259515/how-can-i-split-a-string-into-segments-of-n-characters)

Comment: unluckily, that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: since it seems that your message is actually an encoded list where each item is expected to begin in a new line with an index like `#.) ` you are supposed to decode the list parsing your string to have back your list and later re-encode the specific items slices you are interested into. Or just find using a regex where the string hits `'100. )'`. In javascript there's String.split(separator) but I wouldn't bet that far this could work `msg.split('100. )')`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to test this but I think it might solve your problem.  For every 100 projects store the string in the array `newData`.  Then in the receiver of `newData` loop throught the array of strings and send each individually.

Notice I don't push strings to the array `allLocation` but simply concatinate strings.  Once I've reach a multiple of 100 push that concatinated string to the array `newData`.

```
function SearchbyProjectName(Prjct){
  var projectNON = GetAllProjectNON(); 
  var project = GetAllProject();
  var num = 1;
  var newData = [];
  var allLocation = "xxxheaderxxx";

  var footer = "xxxfooterxxx";
  var limit = 100;

  for (var row=0; row<projectNON.length; row++) {
    if(projectNON[row][3]==Prjct){ 
      var resiNON = num++ + '. ) ' + '/d_' + projectNON[row][6] + '\n\n';
      allLocation.concat(resiNON);
      if( num === limit ) {
        newData.push(allLocation);
        limit = limit+100;
        allLocation = "";
      }
    }
  }
  for (var row=0; row<project.length; row++) {
    if(project[row][3]==Prjct){ 
      var resi = num++ + '. ) ' + '/d_' + project[row][6] + '\n\n';
      allLocation.concat(resi);
      if( num === limit ) {
        newData.push(allLocation);
        limit = limit+100;
        allLocation = "";
      }
    }
  }

  allLocation = allLocation.concat(footer);
  newData.push(allLocation);

  return newData;
}
```

Reference

- [String.concat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp)